# is it possible to Combine image files in a blob

Tags: javascript, image, image-processing, blob, filereader

Let's say I have two images. ('left.jpg','right.jpg').
I would like to load both files, and display them in a single img tag using a blob.
is it possible to display them next to each-other in a single img tag by using 'blob' ?

Comment: Just for completeness, the answer to the title would be "yes", but the one to the body is "no".

Comment: There is also stereoscopic PNG files (using the chunk sTER) which allows you to load left+right using a single img tag. Browser support is not clear however so testing is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, blobs are format agnostic.  They don't understand the underlying file format of the data they represent (jpg, png, etc), all they know is that they have a big chunk of binary data, so they don't know how to combine the files correctly which is what would need to happen.

However, a potential process you could follow would be to:

1. Load the images through [`Image()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)
2. Blit them onto a `<canvas>` with [`drawImage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)
3. Make a data URI out of the image data on the `<canvas>` using [`toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)
4. Set the `src` of the `<img>` to the data URI from step 3

Comment: [toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill) and an other process would be create two `<img>` tags ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Would that be better than a data URI?  I'm just thinking of how best to give the image data to an `<img>` tag; or are you saying something else?

Comment: @Kaiido But the desired final state is a singular `<img>` that shows both images.  As far as I know, you can't set the image data of an `<img>` except through `src`.  I do agree that simply compositing 2 `<img>` with CSS would probably be the most straight forward approach or even leaving them on the `<canvas>`.

Comment: Yes leaving on the canvas was what I was going with right now ;-) But still, my point was that `toBlob` should be preferred over `toDataURL`, even polyfiled. (and now I see I left the hash to the polyfill in my previous comment, that was unintended...)